# add value in array from loop

Tags: php, arrays

How to add multiple values in the place of code from array .
Need to add Following lines

```
'Destination' => $to,
'Destination' => $to,
'Destination' => $to,
'Destination' => $to
```

getting Values from loop like

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
while($res=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$mob [] = $res['recepient'];

}
```

Need to add in following code

```
$params = array('Source' => '923158224535', 
                'Destination' => $mob,
                'Mask' => $sender,
                'Message' => $message,
                'UniCode' => $unicode,   
                'Password' => '123');
```

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same key in an array... what you can do is have `'Destination' => array($to, $to1, $to2))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add values to a two dimensional array dynamically in PHP from a foreach loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864842/add-values-to-a-two-dimensional-array-dynamically-in-php-from-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: This has nothing to do with CakePHP at all, I've changed the tags.

Comment: Please make code for understanding .

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
'Destination' => serialize(array($to,$to1));
```